# Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать запрос в Laravel через Eloquent

Tags: php

```
DB::select("SELECT *
    FROM rates r
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) as max_date, rates.Cur_Code FROM rates GROUP BY rates.Cur_Code) m
    ON r.date = m.max_date AND r.Cur_Code = m.Cur_Code");
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, вы делаете *join* на одну и ту же таблицу?)

Comment: да к той же таблице

Answer (score 0):

Тот пример кода, который Вы привели (наз. еще **Query Builder**), не единственный вариант произведения запросов к базе данных.

*Laravel* предоставляет куда более удобный механизм взаимодействия с БД - [**модели**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) (архитектура [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), все дела), постарайтесь понять и начать использования модели, вместо **Query Builder'a**.

В любом случае, что использования моделей, что использования **Query Builder** *Eloquent* сконструирован по принципу [*Fluent Interface*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), а это значит, что Вы можете вызывать методы "цепочкой":

`DB::table('tableName')->where('columnName', '=', 'value')->get()`

В Вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT *
    FROM rates r
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) as max_date, rates.Cur_Code 
        FROM rates GROUP BY rates.Cur_Code) m
    ON r.date = m.max_date AND r.Cur_Code = m.Cur_Code")
->get();
```

Но, лучше было бы создать модель и работать с ней, это придаст Вашему коду куда более понятный вид.

Comment: Мне как раз нужно узнать как сделать запрос через модель